# C++ Coin Toss Percentage

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that's supposed to request the number of times a user wants to flip a coin, then calculate the percentage of heads (heads is 0, tails is 1) that are tossed. However, my code keeps giving me 0% heads every time I output it. 
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

double percentHeads(int userTosses) {
    srand(4444);
    int tossChance = (rand() % 1);
    int heads = 0;
    double percentCalc = static_cast<double>(heads) / userTosses * 100;  

    for (int i = 1; i <= userTosses; i++) {
        if (tossChance == 0) {
            heads++;
        }
    }
    return percentCalc;
}

int main() {
    int userTosses;
    int tossPercent;
    cout << "Enter the number of times you want to toss the coin: ";
    cin >> userTosses;
    cout << endl;

    tossPercent = percentHeads(userTosses);
    cout << "Heads came up " << tossPercent << "% of the time." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `heads = 0;` so `percentCalc` will always be 0. I think you want to move the assignment of `percentCalc` to just before the `return`. Also, the assignment of `tossChance` should be in the `for` loop.

Comment: `rand() % 1` in `int tossChance = (rand() % 1);` Does not do what you think it does. It does not roll a random integer between 0 and 1. It rolls 0, every time. You can look at the right hand side of the `%` operator as "how many different numbers I want to have a possibility of rolling". Change it to rand() % 2, and it should fix your problem. Also, what Johnny Mopp said.

Comment: [insert usual suggestion to use `<random>`here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the variables in the wrong places. Also, if you are trying to test if `rand()` returns an odd value, you need to do a bitwise AND with one (`rand() & 1`). Or, If you want to see if it's even, do modulo with 2 (`rand() % 2`).

```
double percentHeads(int userTosses) {
    srand(4444);     // You should change this else you'll get same results
    int tossChance;
    int heads = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= userTosses; i++) {
        tossChance = rand() % 2;    // Move this here, and change to 2
        if (tossChance == 0) {
            heads++;
        }
    }
    // and move this here
    double percentCalc = static_cast<double>(heads) / userTosses * 100;  
    return percentCalc;
}
```